# Checking Against Specific Checkboxes with the Answers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, multiple-choice

I have already done a lot of research on Stack Overflow to attempt to answer this question, but most answers are to specific to answer this.

I am attempting to lock questions after the answers are selected and tell the user if the question is right or wrong.

My solution for a Multiple Checkbox style question was to have a 'confirm' button after they select there answers. In this case, I have built a generic function for me to pass the answers to and have them mapped for me. However, I am struggling to come up with a solution for Multiple Checkboxes.

The solution must revolve around javascript/jquery as I do not have control over the HTML generated from this Form Builder that I use.

**TL;DR**

**My solution below fails to correctly recognize wrong answers for Question 14, it should only pop up 'Correct!' if option 3 AND 4 are both selected.**

Currently, it pops up correct if they select 3 and any other option.

For a version to work with: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xg3wt8qx/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="q14" class="q required highlight">
<a class="item_anchor" name="ItemAnchor25"></a>
<span class="question top_question">14. Life policy purchase evaluations include which of the following (choose all that apply):&nbsp;<b class="icon_required" style="color:#FF0000">*</b></span>
<table class="inline_grid">
<tbody><tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="RESULT_CheckBox-25" class="multiple_choice" id="RESULT_CheckBox-25_0" value="CheckBox-0" readonly=""><label for="RESULT_CheckBox-25_0">Insured’s credit rating</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="RESULT_CheckBox-25" class="multiple_choice" id="RESULT_CheckBox-25_1" value="CheckBox-1" readonly=""><label for="RESULT_CheckBox-25_1">Employment history</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="RESULT_CheckBox-25" class="multiple_choice" id="RESULT_CheckBox-25_2" value="CheckBox-2" readonly=""><label for="RESULT_CheckBox-25_2">Medical records</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="RESULT_CheckBox-25" class="multiple_choice" id="RESULT_CheckBox-25_3" value="CheckBox-3" readonly=""><label for="RESULT_CheckBox-25_3">Insurer’s credit rating</label></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var content = document.body.textContent || document.body.innerText;
var hasText = content.indexOf("10. What is the minimum initial investment for a non-retirement investor in this program?")!==-1;

//page 4 questions
if(hasText){
    var correctNumber = [1, 0, 0, 1, 23, 1];
    createQuiz(correctNumber);
}

//Dynamically grabs questions, answers, and creates alert boxes for each section of radio buttons
function createQuiz(correctNumber){

    $("span.question").each(function(i){

        var question = $(this).parent("div").find($(".multiple_choice")).attr("name"); //get the question name attribute
        var parentDiv = $(this).parent("div").attr("id"); //get the parent div id

        //set the alert box HTML
        $(this).parent("div").after("<br><br><br><div id='"+parentDiv+"_success' class='alert alert-success'><strong>Correct!</strong></div><div id='"+parentDiv+"_fail' class='alert alert-danger'><strong>Incorrect!</strong></div>");
        $("#"+parentDiv+"_fail").hide(); //hide alert box
        $("#"+parentDiv+"_success").hide();//hide alert box

        if($(this).parent("div").find($(".multiple_choice")).attr("type")=='radio'){

            $("input[name='"+question+"']").on("click keypress", function(){

                $("input[name='"+question+"']").prop('disabled', true);
                $("input[name='"+question+"']:radio:not(:checked)").attr('disabled', true);
                $(this).attr('disabled', false);

                if($("#"+question+"_"+correctNumber[i]).is(':checked')){
                    $("#"+parentDiv+"_success").show();
                    $("#"+parentDiv+"_fail").hide();
                } 
                else {
                    $("#"+parentDiv+"_success").hide();
                    $("#"+parentDiv+"_fail").show();
                }

                $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
                    contentAsHTML: true,
                    maxWidth: '480',
                    animation: 'grow',
                    side: ['right', 'top', 'bottom', 'left']
                });

            }); //end on click/keypress

        } else if ($(this).parent("div").find($(".multiple_choice")).attr("type")=='checkbox'){

            $("#"+parentDiv+"_success").before("<button id='"+parentDiv+"_confirm' style='width:200px; left:16px; position:relative;' type='button' value='Confirm'>Confirm</button>");

            $("#"+parentDiv+"_confirm").on("click keypress", function(){

                $("input[name='"+question+"']").prop('readonly', true);

                var answers = correctNumber[i].toString().split("");

                for(p=0; p < answers.length; p++){

                    var selected = [];
                    $("input[name='"+question+"']").filter(":checked").each(function() {

                        if(question+"_"+answers[p] == $(this).attr('id') && $("input[name='"+question+"']").filter(":checked").length == answers.length){
                            $("#"+parentDiv+"_success").show();
                            $("#"+parentDiv+"_fail").hide();
                        } 
                        else {
                            $("#"+parentDiv+"_success").hide();
                            $("#"+parentDiv+"_fail").show();
                        }

                    });

                    // if($("#"+question+"_"+answers[p]).is(':checked') && $("input[name='"+question+"']").filter(":checked").length == answers.length){
                    //  $("#"+parentDiv+"_success").show();
                    //  $("#"+parentDiv+"_fail").hide();
                    // } 
                    // else {
                    //  $("#"+parentDiv+"_success").hide();
                    //  $("#"+parentDiv+"_fail").show();
                    // }

                    $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
                        contentAsHTML: true,
                        maxWidth: '480',
                        animation: 'grow',
                        side: ['right', 'top', 'bottom', 'left']
                    });

                } //end for loop

            }); //end on click/keypress

        } //end outer if

    }); //end outer each
} //end createQuiz function



}); //end document ready
```

Comment: I tried in Fiddle, the multiple choice question seems to work fine.

Comment: Did you attempt to answer '4' and any other answer? 3 and 4 work correctly, the problem is that if you select '2' and '4', or '1' and '4', it still pops up correct when it should be incorrect.

Weird, I'm getting different behavior on the actual form, still when you try '3' and '2', it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: the pair of 4 with any other works fine, but the pair of 3 with any other works incorrectly. I think you probably need to edit the info about the bug (change '4' to be '3')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come up with the answer this morning.

My problem was on this for loop, I'm looping through the answers, which I passed 23, if I chose 2 and 4 (or in the fiddle, 1 and 3). Then it responded as correct, because on the last iteration it would find that the last checkbox was check and 2 checkboxes were checked.

```
for(p=0; p < answers.length; p++){

     var selected = [];
     $("input[name='"+question+"']").filter(":checked").each(function() {

        if(question+"_"+answers[p] == $(this).attr('id') && $("input[name='"+question+"']").filter(":checked").length == answers.length){
           $("#"+parentDiv+"_success").show();
           $("#"+parentDiv+"_fail").hide();
        } 
        else {
           $("#"+parentDiv+"_success").hide();
           $("#"+parentDiv+"_fail").show();
        }

     });

} //end for loop
```

My Solution was to Iterate through which checkboxes are checked and return the combined index of which was checked and compare that to the answers.

E.G. I pass '23', they check '1' and '4', '14' != '23', so incorrect.

```
$("#"+parentDiv+"_confirm").on("click keypress", function(){

  $("input[name='"+question+"']").prop('readonly', true);

  var answers = correctNumber[i];

  var input = "";

  $("input[name='"+question+"']").each(function(t){

      if($(this).is(':checked')){
          input = ""+input+t;
      }

  });

  if(input == answers){
      $("#"+parentDiv+"_success").show();
      $("#"+parentDiv+"_fail").hide();
  } 
  else {
      $("#"+parentDiv+"_success").hide();
      $("#"+parentDiv+"_fail").show();
  }


}); //end on click/keypress
```